# How get string between expression with Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, string-concatenation

I would like to get only codes between # and concat it to a new column.

What I have

| id | code |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | (#M05Q01900R00100# = 1) AND (#M05Q01950R00200# = 0) |
| 1 | (#M05Q01900R00100# = 1) AND ((#M05Q01950R00100# = 0) OR (#M05Q01950R00200# = 0)) |
| 2 | (#M05Q01600R00100# = 1) |
| 3 | (#M05Q01125R00200# = 1) |
| 4 | (#M05Q01129R00100# = 1) AND (#M05Q01130R00300# = 0) |
| 5 | (#M05Q01130R00400# = 1) |
| 6 | (#M05Q01132R00100# = 1) |
| 7 | (#M05Q01132R00400# = 1) |
| 8 | (#M05Q01132R00400# = 1) |
| 9 | (#M05Q01140R00200# = 1) |

What I would like to get

| id | code | concat |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | (#M05Q01900R00100# = 1) AND (#M05Q01950R00200# = 0) | M05Q01900R00100, M05Q01950R00200 |
| 1 | (#M05Q01900R00100# = 1) AND ((#M05Q01950R00100# = 0) OR (#M05Q01950R00200# = 0)) | M05Q01900R00100, M05Q01950R00100, M05Q01950R00200 |
| 2 | (#M05Q01600R00100# = 1) | M05Q01600R00100 |
| 3 | (#M05Q01125R00200# = 1) | M05Q01125R00200 |
| 4 | (#M05Q01129R00100# = 1) AND (#M05Q01130R00300# = 0) | M05Q01129R00100, M05Q01130R00300 |
| 5 | (#M05Q01130R00400# = 1) | M05Q01130R00400 |
| 6 | (#M05Q01132R00100# = 1) | M05Q01132R00100 |
| 7 | (#M05Q01132R00400# = 1) | M05Q01132R00400 |
| 8 | (#M05Q01132R00400# = 1) | M05Q01132R00400 |
| 9 | (#M05Q01140R00200# = 1) | M05Q01140R00200 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.findall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) with regex for values between `#` and then [`Series.str.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.join.html):

```
df['concat'] = df['code'].str.findall(r'#(.*?)#').str.join(', ')
print (df)
   id                                                code  \
0    0  (#M05Q01900R00100# = 1) AND (#M05Q01950R00200#...   
1    1  (#M05Q01900R00100# = 1) AND ((#M05Q01950R00100...   
2    2                            (#M05Q01600R00100# = 1)   
3    3                            (#M05Q01125R00200# = 1)   
4    4  (#M05Q01129R00100# = 1) AND (#M05Q01130R00300#...   
5    5                            (#M05Q01130R00400# = 1)   
6    6                            (#M05Q01132R00100# = 1)   
7    7                            (#M05Q01132R00400# = 1)   
8    8                            (#M05Q01132R00400# = 1)   
9    9                            (#M05Q01140R00200# = 1)   

                                              concat  
0                   M05Q01900R00100, M05Q01950R00200  
1  M05Q01900R00100, M05Q01950R00100, M05Q01950R00200  
2                                    M05Q01600R00100  
3                                    M05Q01125R00200  
4                   M05Q01129R00100, M05Q01130R00300  
5                                    M05Q01130R00400  
6                                    M05Q01132R00100  
7                                    M05Q01132R00400  
8                                    M05Q01132R00400  
9                                    M05Q01140R00200
```